# How to output looped data into nested lists?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [
     [
      ['game1_teamA_player_1_a', 'game1_teamA_player_1_b', 'game1_teamA_player_1_c'],
      ['game1_teamB_player_2_a', 'game1_teamB_player_2_b', 'game1_teamB_player_2_c']
     ],

     [
      ['game2_teamA_player_1_a', 'game2_teamA_player_1_b', 'game2_teamA_player_1_c'],
      ['game2_teamB_player_2_a', 'game2_teamB_player_2_b', 'game2_teamB_player_2_c']
     ]
    ]

inj_main = []

for b in a: #  2 teams per game

    for c in b: #  3 stats per player, 2 players per team
        inja = c[0]
        injb = c[1]
        injc = c[2]
        inj_html = '<tr>' + inja + '</tr><tr>' + injb + '</tr><tr>' + injc + '</tr>'
        inj_main.append(inj_html)

print(inj_main)
```

I am trying to take the data in list`a` and append HTML `<tr>` tags and return them back to the same list format as `a`.  `a` consists of 2 games, each game has 2 teams, each team has 2 players and each player has 3 stats.  My goal is to call `a[0]` and have it return the 2 teams with the players info nested inside. When I print `inj_main` now, it returns everything inside the same list. I can't figure out how to nest it properly.

Current Output:

```
['<tr>game1_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game1_teamA_player_1_b</tr<tr>game1_teamA_player_1_c</tr>', 

 '<tr>game1_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_c</tr>', 

 '<tr>game2_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game2_teamA_player_1_b</tr><tr>game2_teamA_player_1_c</tr>', 

 '<tr>game2_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_c</tr>']
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  ['<tr>game1_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game1_teamA_player_1_b</tr><tr>game1_teamA_player_1_c</tr>', 

   '<tr>game1_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_c</tr>'
  ], 

  ['<tr>game2_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game2_teamA_player_1_b</tr><tr>game2_teamA_player_1_c</tr>', 

   '<tr>game2_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_c</tr>'
  ]
]
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: First, format your code to be readable: stringing over 400 characters on one line greatly detracts from the readability, hampering our desire and ability to help you.
Second, *specify* the output you want, including an example.  "Nested list" is far too generic to know what you have in mind.

Comment: It may be worth considering a template engine such as [jinja2](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) if you're going to do any non-trivial HTML generation.

Comment: You should dictionary for this type of data structure.which is far more efficient.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the tips. I updated my desired output.

Comment: I'll wait until the post is more reader-friendly.

Comment: I think what you need is pass the `inj_html`to a `list(inj_html` to make a list out of it first and then add it to the main list?

Comment: @joeFerndz Thanks for cleaning up my mess. I tried to go in and fix it but it said you already got to it. Thanks again

Comment: Hopefully this looks much better now. Btw, question for you @user15187208, Is the list `a` a list of list of list?

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yes. `a` is a list with 2 items, each of those values has 2 items, and each of those has 3 items.  A list of lists of lists.  I couldnt make this any more complicated if I tried lol. Thanks

Comment: Your code is good. All you need to do is to `inj_main = list(inj_main)`

Comment: @JoeFerndz Thanks, I tried that but its not creating 2 lists.

Comment: I found the problem. See my answer. You need to store the inner loop results to a temp list and then add the temp list to the main list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make minor changes to your code to get you the results.

You need to capture the list from your inner loop and store it as a list to the main list (inj_main). To do that, you need to create a temporary list and store it.

See my code with comments on the changes.

```
a = [
     [
      ['game1_teamA_player_1_a', 'game1_teamA_player_1_b', 'game1_teamA_player_1_c'],
      ['game1_teamB_player_2_a', 'game1_teamB_player_2_b', 'game1_teamB_player_2_c']
     ],

     [
      ['game2_teamA_player_1_a', 'game2_teamA_player_1_b', 'game2_teamA_player_1_c'],
      ['game2_teamB_player_2_a', 'game2_teamB_player_2_b', 'game2_teamB_player_2_c']
     ]
    ]

inj_main = []

for b in a: #  2 teams per game
    inj_temp = [] #setup a temp list
    for c in b: #  3 stats per player, 2 players per team
        inja = c[0]
        injb = c[1]
        injc = c[2]
        inj_html = '<tr>' + inja + '</tr><tr>' + injb + '</tr><tr>' + injc + '</tr>'

        inj_temp.append(inj_html) #add to temp list

    inj_main.append(inj_temp) #add the temp list to main list

print(inj_main)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[
  ['<tr>game1_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game1_teamA_player_1_b</tr><tr>game1_teamA_player_1_c</tr>', 

   '<tr>game1_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_c</tr>'
  ], 

  ['<tr>game2_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game2_teamA_player_1_b</tr><tr>game2_teamA_player_1_c</tr>', 

   '<tr>game2_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_c</tr>'
  ]

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [
    [
        ['game1_teamA_player_1_a', 'game1_teamA_player_1_b', 'game1_teamA_player_1_c'],
        ['game1_teamB_player_2_a', 'game1_teamB_player_2_b', 'game1_teamB_player_2_c']
    ],
    [
        ['game2_teamA_player_1_a', 'game2_teamA_player_1_b', 'game2_teamA_player_1_c'],
        ['game2_teamB_player_2_a', 'game2_teamB_player_2_b', 'game2_teamB_player_2_c']
    ]
]

for b in range(len(a)):
    for c in range(len(a[b])):
        for d in range(len(a[b][c])):
            a[b][c][d] = "<tr>"+a[b][c][d]+"</tr>"
        a[b][c] = "".join(a[b][c])
print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
[
    ['<tr>game1_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game1_teamA_player_1_b</tr><tr>game1_teamA_player_1_c</tr>',
    '<tr>game1_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game1_teamB_player_2_c</tr>'
    ],
    ['<tr>game2_teamA_player_1_a</tr><tr>game2_teamA_player_1_b</tr> <tr>game2_teamA_player_1_c</tr>',
    '<tr>game2_teamB_player_2_a</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_b</tr><tr>game2_teamB_player_2_c</tr>'
    ]
]
```

If you need to keep the original `a`, you can make a copy of it with `a.copy()` first.